# Как проверять поле модели в xaml?

Tags: wpf

У меня есть коллекция:

```
public ObservableCollection<AccessPointTransmissionModel> AccessPointTransmission { get; } = new();
```

Ее модель:

```
public class AccessPointTransmissionModel
{
    public MessageType Type { get; set; }
    public LocalTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public MqttDelivery? Delivery { get; set; }
    public string? TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

А вот `ListBoх` в xaml, к которому все биндится:

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding AccessPointTransmission}"/>
```

Мне необходимо проверять Type в коллекции. Если Type будет равен "Event", то этот элемент должен быть слева, иначе справа
Ну т.е я каким-то образом должен применить HorizontalAlignment, в зависимости от Type. Как это сделать?

**update**

Попробовал написать конвертер, но не особо понятно, как это применить

```
public object? Convert( object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    => ( MessageType ) value == MessageType.Command                                             
        ? HorizontalAlignment.Right                                                             
        : HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы изначально не так проектируете все. Если у вас объекты сообщений разные (разные свойства например, два разных класса), то сделайте интерфейс и сделайте коллекцию этих интерфейсов, а в XAML задайте под каждый тип свой `DataTemplate` (`<DataTemplate DataType="нужный тип">Нужный вид.</DateTemplate>`), а если у вас разный дизайн должен быть на основе одного свойства, то для этого делают триггеры, через которые можно хоть полностью сменить вид объекта.

Answer (score 0):

все оказалось как-то проще, сделал так:

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding AccessPointTransmission}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">                       
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                             
        <DataTemplate>                                                                                 
            <Grid>                                                                                     
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>                      
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Delivery.Header.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>         
            </Grid>                                                                                    
        </DataTemplate>                                                                                
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                            
</ListBox>
```